# RemoveEventHandler doesn't work in IText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I have added an EventHandler to my PdfDocument, and for a specific part of pdf, I want to remove my handler and I have to add the same handler to the PdfDocument.

```
 var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
 var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
 var document = new Document(pdfDocument);

 // Page Number Event Handling
 var pageNumberEvtHandler = new PageNumberEventHandler(model.DocumentNo);

categoryPageData.ForEach(data => 
{
    pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, pageNumberEvtHandler);
                 
    // This method is simply creates a Table and adds it to the document.   
    CreateCategoryPageLayout(document, data.Category);

    // I don't want paging in image pages, so I'd like to remove my Handler.
    pdfDocument.RemoveEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, pageNumberEvtHandler);
   
    // This method is creates an Image from ImageDataFactory and adds it to a Table then to the document. 
    CreateCategoryImagePage(document, data.Image);
}
```

But it seems, `RemoveEventHandler` does not removes the handler. Confused in here, thanks in advance. :)

**NOTE: I've noticed that, only for the last page, it successfully removes the event listener, but for the previous pages it didn't**

Comment: Please attach the self-contained runnable code sample. Right now there are a lot of dependencies which make it impossible for someone else to run the code and tweaking the code takes time and creates additional difference from your flow

Comment: Of course I will attach the runnable code, but on the other hand the problem is, addevent -> document.add(table) -> removeevent in a foreach loop is not working as expected, for your information